# Communication between two Flex mobile applications over a network

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have two mobile devices on a local network, **A** and **B**. I would ideally like **A** to be able call functions on **B**, returning a response to **A**.

I am aware of [LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html), but unfortunately this isn't supported on mobile. What is the best way to achieve this? Do I have to setup **B** as a server using **BlaseDS**?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that one of the Adobe evangelists had a mobile app (A Game Othello) that would communicate w/ other devices directly.  http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/04/one_application_five_screens.html I'm not sure if he ever released the code for the version that talks to others.  I found a link to the code base; I'd start by looking there.

Comment: From watching the video it looks as though this does no network stuff but rather is a demonstration of running the same app on a number of platforms?

Comment: I'm sure he had an update which which would allow one instance of the app to communicate with another instance of the app; completely independent of the devices it was working on.  You'd have to see if that code is actually posted in his github repository, though.  I don't know how it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use p2p. I think this [article](http://blog.leeburrows.com/2011/10/p2p-flash-on-a-local-network-part1/) would be helpfull to you. It is about p2p interaction of swfs on a local network.